# Is there a way to parse an expression from a string and resolve its type in a scope using JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

Suppose I have the following code

```
class A{
  public void f(int i, int j){
    // line
  }
}
```

what I want to do is to

1. parse the code using JDT parser;
2. take an input string, e.g. `i + j`, from somewhere, parse the string using JDT parser and get an AST of type `Expression`; and
3. resolve the type of that `Expression` AST and get it's type `int`.

1 and 2 seem easy enough. But I couldn't figure out how 3 can be done in JDT. Has anyone any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I meant to parse the string in the scope of method `f`, so that both `i` and `j` are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to work with [bindings](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html#sec-bindings) (link is deprecated but information still valid).

Note: [how binding resolving is activated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791105/1091453) - an answer I gave.

---

With bindings available you can I do the following:

```
Expression expr = ...;
ITypeBinding binding = expr.resolveTypeBinding();
// binding is e.g. 'int' for 'i + j';
```

---

Note: to have valid Java code you must insert a statement and not an expression. So an naive approach could be:

1. add expression as statement e.g. `Object $expr = i + j;`
2. save type-binding `binding = expr.resolveTypeBinding() // e.g. ITypeBinding 'int';`
3. replace `Object $expr` placeholder with type according to `binding` - going from `binding` back to `ASTNode` (most likely `PrimitiveType`) must be done manually.

If you need a simple code sample, just ask.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it should work. The challenge in my questions is that the expressions whose types i want to resolve are built at runtime. It's possible to construct a new java file with all the new expressions inserted to the method and then parse the file and resolve the types, but it seems rather cumbersome to me. I'm wondering if there is a way to specify a parsing context (e.g. including the local variables, arguments, surrounding classes) and parse just expressions or statements within that context.