# How to distinguish a user-defined class and API class using Eclipse JDT ITypeBinding

Tags: eclipse, parsing, eclipse-jdt, method-invocation

I am using the following code while parsing a method invocation:

```java
ITypeBinding typeBinding = node.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding();
if ( typeBinding != null) //type resolution found actual type
    {
        className = typeBinding.getName();
    }
```

where className is a String containing the name of the type. Is there a way to distinguish between user-defined Java class names and API class names or external/included library class names in a method invocation?

For example, given a complete invocation `String.valueOf(c);`, I want to detect `String` as a non-user-defined class name with a method invocation `valueOf`.

For the following code snippet:
`MyCalculator calc = new MyCalculator();
calc.add(1,2);`

Given the invocation `calc.add(1,2)`, I want to detect `MyCalculator` as a user-defined class name with a method invocation `add`

I am including a code snippet showing how I set up parsing. Maybe someone can point put any errors in the setup.

```
 private static CompilationUnit parse(String unit) {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);

    File f = new File(currentFilePath);        
    String unitName = f.getName();
    parser.setUnitName(unitName);

    String[] sources = {Constants.SOURCES}; 
    String[] classpath = {Constants.CLASSPATH};

    parser.setEnvironment(classpath, sources, new String[] { "UTF-8"}, true);
    parser.setSource(unit.toCharArray());

    return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); 
}
```

where `Constants.SOURCES` is `public static String SOURCES = "F:\\BluetoothChat";` the path to the root folder of the Java project being parsed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'library class'?

Comment: Do you mean [`typeBinding.isFromSource()`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ITypeBinding.html#isFromSource())?

Comment: @greg-449 I mean any class from imported external packages or included external libraries. For example, the class `MethodDeclaration` is from Eclipse JDT.

Comment: @howlger I used it and got `false` for a user-defined Java class.

Comment: @greg-449 I have replaced _library class_ with _API class_ in the question title. Also, I have add examples in the body of my question to explain my requirement.

Comment: By _user-defined_ class/type do you mean a class/type not of the system library? Which of the following are _user-defined_: `String` (system library), `int` (primitives), `A` of a JAR, `B` of a class folder, `C` of a dependent project and `D` of a source folder? What about classes/types of exported vs. not exported (internal) packages?

Comment: @howlger I consider class `D` from a source folder of a project as a _user-defined class_ of that project. Dependent project class `C` should be considered as _external user-defined class_. `A` should be considered as _API class_. `String` is also an _API class_.

Comment: @howlger, I have added code for creating an AST in the body of my question. Maybe this setup is affecting the value of `typeBinding.isFromSource()`

Answer (score 2):

JDT's [Java Model](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_int_model.htm) has the notion that every `IType` is contained in an `IPackageFragment` which is rooted in an `IPackageFragmentRoot`. The latter represents either a source folder or a library (jar, class folder etc.).

This means, if you have resolved AST (DOM), you could ask the `ITypeBinding` representing the method receiver: `getJavaElement()`. The result should actually be an `IType`, which will tell you its package fragment root if you just say `type.getAncestor(IJavaElement.PACKAGE_FRAGMENT_ROOT)`.

Looking at the package fragment root there are several options to figure out, what exactly you have, e.g., `isArchive()`. Also `getResolvedClasspathEntry()` can tell you, how this thing got pulled into compilation. Based on this information you can draw whatever line you wish between "your" code and "API".

Comment: `IType j = (IType)typeBinding.getJavaElement();` gives me null value for `j`. Also, `typeBinding` has a MissingTypeBinding value for `binding`. Any solutions?

Comment: Seeing a `MissingTypeBinding` looks like the ASTParser doesn't have a sufficient environment for resolving all necessary types. Please double-check your `classpath`.

Comment: This answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791105 provides 2 approaches to instantiate the ASTParser correctly.